How to Stream RTSP Video from IP Camera to HTML Video Element?
I have an IP camera that streams video using the RTSP protocol. My system needs to connect to this IP camera and stream the video to a web browser. Since most browsers don't natively support RTSP, I need an intermediary server to handle the RTSP stream. I implemented a FastAPI web server that uses OpenCV to connect to the IP camera and stream the video, and it works; I can see the video in the browser.
Currently, my implementation streams the video as an image element, but I want to stream it as a video element. How can I achieve this with my server?
Additionally, are there any ready-to-use servers that can stream video from an IP camera to an HTML video element that you would recommend?
Is streaming the video as a JPEG efficient?
Reading frame from IP camera implementation:
class VideoStreamService:

def __init__(self):
    pass

def get_frame(self, connection_string: str):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(connection_string)

    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        success, frame = cap.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, encodded_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            # frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodded_frame) + b'\r\n') 

Stream response from the server:
def get_video_stream(
    connection_string: str = Query(..., alias="connection_string"),
    video_stream_service: VideoStreamService = Depends(Provide[Container.video_stream_service]),) -> StreamingResponse:
    try:
        encodded_frame = video_stream_service.get_frame(unquote(connection_string))
        return StreamingResponse(encodded_frame, media_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
    except ValueError as error:
        ...

I used this SO question as a reference to my implementation

I successfully converted RTSP to HLS, which is supported by HTML5, using the guide at https://docs.cvedia.com/tutorials/rtsp_to_hls.html.
Are there any production-ready servers that can perform this conversion?

HTML5 supports various protocols, such as HLS and WebRTC. For my use case, HLS was effective, and I used FFMPEG to convert from RTSP. You can set up your own server to host the HLS playlist and video files, which can then be played using a video element.
example for FFmpeg command ffmpeg -i rtsp://<camera_address>/stream -c copy -hls_list_size 10 -hls_segment_type fmp4 output.m3u8
